# Sign an APK exported from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, publish, keystore

I am trying to post an app created through Apache Cordova using Visual Studio 2015. I have been able to export the .APK successfully but I have not been able to find a keystore in order to sign this .APK so I can post it.

I can not find a keystore anywhere in the Visual Studio project build and whenever I try to run the CMD it says that I have an "Illegal Option: aaaa-key.keystore keytool -genkeypair" and doesn't generate a Keystore.

If there is no Keystore generated by the IDE (that I could find) and my CMD isn't creating one as instructed from MSN then I feel kind of stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a new key with this command:

First open cmd and then type:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\bin
```

Then run:

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore YourKeyName.keystore ^
        -alias YourKeyName -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```